# NFS server for Windows

Tags: filesystems

I am looking for a lightweight and simple NFS server that I could have running on Windows XP which allows some other NFS clients to connect to it. If possible, it should be free of charge.

Answer (score 4):

You can install the [Windows Services for UNIX](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=896C9688-601B-44F1-81A4-02878FF11778&displaylang=en). Version 3.5 has been made available for legacy versions of Windows free of charge and it includes an NFS server and client nicely integrated into the system.

Comment: We've used this on several machines and it seems to work pretty good.  You may have to do a little tuning if you're primarily transferring very large files, but otherwise it's pretty straight forward.

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: @Dale: The product no longer works anyway.

Comment: Any reference concerning how/why it no longer works?  This link seems to lead to a copy of the software: https://dev.to/wincentbalin/download-link-for-microsoft-windows-services-for-unix-3-5-555p